# Creating a new build user in TFS 2010

Tags: tfsbuild

I have TFS2010 and I am trying to setup automated builds.  But becuase the build folders were on a diferent server i need changed the user to my user becuase I have write access to thoese folders.  the problem I am having now, is that i am getting this error:

```
TF215106: Access denied. MYUSER needs Update build information permissions for build definition MYPROJECT.Build in team project MYPROJECT
```

i dont want to keep the user under my name but I need to be able to tell the Network Team how to configure the system, so I am using my user the guinea pig.

**SOLUTION**
This could of been from lack of experience managing TFS, but I had to set the security directly on the build definition.  It took a bunch of reading to realize their was security on the build definition.  Once you I opened the security window, it was the same as adding users to any other security feature in windows.

Comment: This is not a folder permission error, it's a TFS permission error. Check the user has those permissions.

Comment: I added the user to the TFS_BUILD_Serivce_WPG group in Server Manager (Ts-TFS) -> Configuration -> Local Users and groups.  restarted the servies and that didnt change anything.  where am I suppose to add the permissions I am new to setting up TFS

Answer (score 0):

Bring up the TFS Admin Console on the Build Server.  Check what service account is used the build service.  Make sure that service account has read/write access to the build drop share.